# How can I disable the days which out of the current month in Fullcalendar?

Tags: fullcalendar

In Fullcalendar, I want to disable the days which out of the current month.
For example , maybe these days are the last month days or next month days. I want to disable them, who can tell me how to make it to be disabled?

And how to disable the range of time in one day,  For example , to disable `6:00AM-8:00AM`.

Answer (score 1):

To disable the days which are out of the current month, there's a CSS class on those days "fc-other-month" which you could either use some CSS or JQuery/javascript to disable the events dayClick and eventClick.  To work with the time range, the documentation has a minTime: http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/docs/agenda/minTime/ and maxTime: http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/docs/agenda/maxTime/ to work with, but these will apply to every day in your calendar, not a specific day.  You could always add an event yourself during that timeframe for a specific day and set the attribute: editable to false.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! Disabling specific day is work. Could you give me an example that how to disable the range of Time in one day?  For example 6:00AM-8:00AM ,in that time, users cannot add/edit any events. Thank you!